# Recursively read xls sheets in R

Tags: r, xls

I have several .xls file, with different number of sheets, in my Data directory. I need to read all of the sheets in the files and put them into a single list. I think to use two loops to recursively read each sheet in each file and append it into the list.

The problem is because each time I read a new file it overwrite the same "level" in the list, of the previous file. So the first level (sheet 1) of the first file is overwritten by the first level (sheet 1) of the second file, that is overwritten by the first level (sheet 1) of the third file and so on.

How can I append all the sheet of all the files with no re-inizialization of the list each time a read a new file?

This is the code I wrote:

```
files <- list.files()
listGil <- list()
for(i in seq_along(files)){
    s <- sheetCount(files[i])
                        for(k in 1:s)
                    {
                        listGil[[k]] <- read.xls(files[i], sheet = k)
                    }
}
```

To Upload a running code, for this kind of problem, could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to read all the xls files into one big list, and skip the `for` loop altogether:

```
big_list = lapply(files, read.xls)
```

And be careful with creating empty objects, and filling them iteratively. Each time the object grows, a new piece of memory needs to be allocated. This can become veeeeery slow when the amount of files you need to read is large. The solution above using `lapply` does not suffer from this problem.

Of if you also want to read the worksheets, you can use mapply:

```
big_list = mapply(read.xls, xls = files, sheet = 1:4)
```

Assuming you want to read the first four sheets.

Comment: The use of lapply speed-up the code, but it reads only the first sheet of each xls file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use a list of lists (I think this is better):

```
files <- list.files()
listGil <- vector(mode='list',length(files))
for(i in seq_along(files)){
    s <- sheetCount(files[i])
    listGil[[i]] <- vector(mode='list',s)
                        for(k in 1:s)
                    {
                        listGil[[i]][[k]] <- read.xls(files[i], sheet = k)
                    }
}
```

2) Use only 1 list:

```
files <- list.files()
listGil <- list()
for(i in seq_along(files)){
    s <- sheetCount(files[i])
                        for(k in 1:s)
                    {
                        listGil[[length(listGil)+1]] <- read.xls(files[i], sheet = k)
                    }
}
```